# How to determine if it is an invoice journal or payment journal?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am required to extract **posted** payment journals and I've used **LedgerJournalTable**. However, I've seen that invoice journal and payment journal are both in that table. Is there any way or is there a unique field that can distinguished if a journal is an invoice or payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `LedgerJournalTable.JournalType` backed by the base enum `LedgerJournalType` (with more than 40 values) can be used to distinguish the journal type.